# Solve for differential equation whose RHS consists of 2 different functions in two different intervals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here's the problem:

> $$y'(x)-y(x) = \begin{cases}
> 1, & x \leq 1\\ 
> x-1, & x>1
> \end{cases}, \ \ y(0) = 2$$

Here's my attempt:

$ x \leq 1$:

$y'(x) - y(x) = 1$

Using integrating factor we have:

$ d/dx(y(x)e^{-x}) = e^{-x} $

Solving for $y(x)$ we have:

$y(x) = Ce^x-1$, for some real constant $C$. In this case, since $y(0) = 2$, $C = 3$. Hence, $y(x) = 3e^x-1$ for the given interval.

$ x > 1$:

$y'(x) - y(x) = x-1$

Using integrating factor, we have that:

$d/dx[y(x)e^{-x}] = e^{-x}(x-1)$

Integrating on the LHS and RHS in x we get:

$y(x)e^{-x} = \int e^{-x}(x-1)dx = -xe^{-x}+C \Rightarrow y(x) = -x+Ce^x$

However, I don't know how to pick $C$ in this case, as $y(0) = 2$ only can be applied for our first interval. I'd be glad if you had any tips.

I also wonder whether you may have another problem like this one, as I found it really fun :)

Comment: @user376343 Sorry I can't see where in my answer you found it. Could you clarify for me

Comment: sorry if my comment was misleading. I delete it.

Comment: Because you have solved the problem for $x\leq 1$, you have the value of $y(1)$ and you can use it as initial condition for solving your equation for $x>1$.

Comment: @user376343 No problem :)

Comment: @PierreCarre Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have concluded that, for $x\leq 1$, we have $y(x)= 3e^x-1$. So, we can now solve the IVP
$$
\begin{cases}
y(1) = 3e-1\\ y'(x)-y(x)=x-1,
\end{cases}
$$

which will give you $y(x)=3e^x-x, \quad x > 1$.

Comment: What is the justification for stating that $f$ should be continuous at $1$ ?

Comment: @zwim That  entirely depends on what  you define to be the solution of a differential equation. Normally, one requires that the solution of an IVP of the form $y'=f(t,y)$ is actually $C^1$.

Comment: Yes, but here $f$ is not even continuous ($1$ and $x-1$ discontinuous in $x=1$), so $C^1$ is excluded. I would say that choosing $C=3$ effectively gives us the more regular solution, but I'm not really sure that it is mandatory, hence my question.

Comment: @zwim I'd say that since we cannot hope to have $C^1$ regularity we start relaxing our definition of solution. When we "set" $y(1)=3e-1$ we are searching for $C^1$ solutions on $(0, 1)\cup (1,T)$ that are  continuous on $[0,T]$.